# What is best practice when using dumpdata --natural-key?

Tags: django

When using [dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-dumpdata-natural-foreign), Django recommends using `natural_key()` to serialize objects that refer to `Permission` or `ContentType`:

> --natural-foreign
>
> Uses the `natural_key()` model method to serialize any foreign key and
> many-to-many relationship to objects of the type that defines the
> method. If you’re dumping contrib.auth Permission objects or
> contrib.contenttypes ContentType objects, you should probably use this
> flag. See the natural keys documentation for more details on this and
> the next option.

This means that rather than dumping `foreignkey` contentype with `pk=1`, it is dumped as:

```
"content_type": [
  "myapp",
  "mymodel"
],
```

- Why would you not always use `--natural-key`?
- What use cases are there where `--natural-key` would be inappropriate?